# Pandoc - Citations don't link to the reference

Tags: citing, pandoc, markdown

I am using Markdown to write the text and Pandoc to convert that text to a PDF.
My problem is that the citations are correctly being generated in the PDF (eg. [@somekey] is converted to [1]) but they don't link to the actual reference, that's generated on the last page. I cannot click the citation (eg. [1]) to get to the reference (eg. [1] Djikstra - Some Book). Internet links are clickable as usual.

A concrete example is the following:

test.md

```
Some text that needs a citation. [@somekey]
```

test.bib

```
@misc{somekey,
  title = {{sometitle}},
  howpublished = {https://www.google.com}
}
```

Command to convert to pdf:

```
pandoc -o test.pdf  --citeproc --bibliography=test.bib test.md
```

The PDF looks like this (with the mouse pointer where I would expect the link):

[image]

The intermediate .tex file generated like this:

```
pandoc -o test.tex  --citeproc --bibliography=test.bib test.md
```

looks like this:

test.tex

```
Some text that needs a citation. ({``{sometitle},''} n.d.)

\hypertarget{refs}{}
\begin{CSLReferences}{1}{0}
\leavevmode\vadjust pre{\hypertarget{ref-somekey}{}}%
{``{sometitle}.''} n.d. https://www.google.com.

\end{CSLReferences}
```

[I found this old thread that documented, that linking should work as it was fixed 7 years ago.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675890/add-hyperlinks-for-citations-figures-sections-by-using-pandoc-and-markdown-to)

Can somebody please help me find out, why it doesn't work for me? Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the intermediate .tex file?

Comment: Please add it to your question. Please add a compilable reproducible example and not just a code fragment. Do you compile the tex file often enough? (at least two times)

Comment: Where can we find `eva.csl`? A quick search resulted in https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/eva-berlin-konferenz.csl, is that the same style?

Comment: @Patryk Please don't add code fragments. Make a compilable reproducible example so we can check if there is any code around the citation which would make it in theory clickable. If there is not, than that's a problem with pandoc and not a latex problem and would hence be off-topic.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz of course I agree that a reproducible example is needed, however I don't agree that modifying Pandoc output is off-topic, we have many questions about that (also for other tools that generate LaTeX code).

Comment: @Marijn I updated the question with an example that doesn't use a custom .csl

Comment: IMHO this is a question, how to use pandoc to produce short links in PDFs or generated TeX. It is not a TeX question, because the generated TeX code already does not have a link where it is expected. So IMHO this question is off-topic here.

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513465/make-pandoc-link-whole-citation-instead-of-only-the-year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What was missing was to define that citations should link in the metadata by using the command like

```
pandoc -o test.pdf -M link-citations=true --citeproc --bibliography=test.bib test.md
```

See https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#other-relevant-metadata-fields

> link-citations
>
> If true, citations will be hyperlinked to the corresponding bibliography entries (for author-date and numerical styles only). Defaults to false.

Comment: Note that, as samcarter commented, in author-year styles (like the one in your MWE above) only the year is linked and not the author, which is expected behavior.